# How to create a dynamic list of class instances within the same class

Tags: .net, class, types, instance, user-defined-types

I feel this question exists somewhere but I haven't found anything about the dynamic part of it which is why I'm attempting to ask the question differently.

Assume I have class called `UDT` (User Defined Type) which has a set of properties. This set of properties is NOT fixed and can range from 1 property to maybe 50 (It can vary, that's all). Now assume I have a second class called `ClassicType` which can a fixed number of properties BUT, all its properties are of a native type (Int, Float, String, Datetime, Bool, etc.)

**Question 1**

How can I structure the `UDT` class to be able to contain a variable amount of `UDT` instances and/or `ClassicType` instances ? Below is a pseudo-code of what I imagine the structure to be like

```
public class UDT
{
    String UDTName = "A new type";
    List<UDT> nonClassicProperties = // A dynamic list containing 0 or more UDT instances
    List<ClassicType> classicProperties = // A dynamic list containing 0 or more ClassicType instances
    // Other properties specific to a UDT object
}

public class ClassicType
{
    String name = "Random name";
    int age = 26;
    bool alive = true;
    float price = 50.5;
}
```

**Question 2**

Could I extract all `ClassicType` instances from a `UDT` instance by iterating over the recursive list till its empty ?

Thanks in advance !

**NOTE**

Please ask me for more details or explanations if you are unable to grasp what I am trying to do (Before downvoting or closing the question).

I will gladly take a link to an existing answer which fits my requirements !

**EDIT 1**

The use of these two classes is to populate a database more easily. The only class that will be pushed to the database is the contents of the `ClassicType` which will create a table based on its properties. The `UDT` class will be used to easily create copies of different objects with all the properties it includes.

**EDIT 2**

Here is a diagram showing how the structure could look.

```
UDT instance (Call it SpecialObject)
|-> UDT instance
|   |-> UDT instance
|   |   |-> ClassicType instance
|   |-> ClassicType instance
|-> Classic Type instance
```

With this diagram, the `SpecialObject` would have 3 `ClassicType` properties where each one belongs to a different UDT instance and therefore has a different hierarchical level.

Comment: Please, show how do you use both classes. Btw, why don't use built-in `Type` class?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski is that better ?

Comment: "Better" term leads to opinions rather then facts. It isn't fully clear which problem do you want to solve and why do you need own structures for types instead of built-in ones

Comment: The need is explained. I need to create a UDT so that I can easily duplicate properties when I combine multiple UDT instances. I will add a diagram to show how it could be structured.